# Wallet gone, how to get it back?

Tags: multibit, lost-wallet

So I had my Bitcoin wallet at Multibit and due to computer problems I formatted my hard drive and the wallet within it. I have no backups of the wallet, I have only my account name. Are my Bitcoins now gone forever?

Comment: You might be able to recover your files to a prior to format state if you take your HD off your computer immediately and use the proper software. Then you might be also able to recover your wallet.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "account name".  I can't find any reference to Multibit using such a thing.  Can you explain what you mean?  Maybe a screenshot of where in the program you would enter this?

Answer (score 1):

I would check these help pages out. The first one explains that your wallet may not be fully deleted.

> https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_support_missingWallets.html
>   https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_lostOrForgottenPassword.html

Multibit has a pretty good troubleshooting page too, which explains where all their data is stored. I would check and see if you have any data in your system specific directory.

> https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_troubleshooting.html

If the wallet is truly deleted, and you don't have any backups, then yes, unfortunately your bitcoins are gone forever. :/

Comment: I still have my account name. Is that same thing as private key? Can I somehow return my wallet using that?

Comment: The account name is nothing like the private key.